# Phonegap Websockets iOS 8

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a Phonegap app implementing websockets (as several other people have done on here) strictly for iOS but I cannot seem to get the call to run.  I am aware that iOS now allows websockets, and several older solutions are out of date.  Does anyone have a more recent tutorial or demonstration of websockets via phonegap for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I found there is no special implementation needed, and despite my best efforts there was actually an error with my javascript, and when editing in Phonegap be careful which files you are modifying, as Phonegap will keep copies for each platform as well as a master version